# Unable to Bind Address Error when Configuring IPv6 Transport Proxy in Docker

Tags: docker, go

I'm developing a simple IPv6 transport proxy, which can be found in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/Jannchie/6tp. The proxy allows me to use any IP address within the IPv6 network segment as a proxy to access the target website.

I added the route:

```bash
ip route add local xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth0
```

and, enabled bind any IP:

```bash
sysctl net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

When I run the proxy locally and execute the following command, it works fine and returns a different IP address each time:

```bash
curl -x "0.0.0.0:4747" ipv6.ip.sb
```

However, when I deploy it in Docker, I'm unable to access it properly and encounter the following error:

```bash
$ docker run -p 4747:4747 jannchie/6tp --subnet=xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 --proxy-address="[::]:4747"
2023/06/04 14:19:43 Starting proxy server on [::]:4747
2023/06/04 14:19:45 http: proxy error: dial tcp [xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:1f9:523e:35]:0->[2a09:0:13::9]:80: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Currently, the only way I can avoid this problem is by using the --network=host option.

Could you please provide guidance on how to correctly configure this proxy to run within Docker?

Comment: Without `--network=host`, the container's network is isolated from the host network. Use host networking to keep things simpler.